# Video Player in Ububtu 14.04

Tags: vlc, video-player

I am trying to download vlc to play movies but it is not working. When i go to software center and try to install vlc it says "Package dependencies cannot be resolved" 
I am not to ububtu and linux can some one guide what needs to be done?

Comment: Open a terminal (Ctrl+Shit+T) and run this command `sudo apt-get install vlc` and post the messages in your answer.

Comment: Did you try?: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc

Comment: try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: AB: this is what i am getting in return of the command you gave                            The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.0-0ubuntu0.14.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not installable or
                libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11) but it is not installable
       Depends: libavutil54 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not installable

Comment: Depends: libva1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not installable
       Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0~pre1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not installable
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.0-0ubuntu0.14.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.0-0ubuntu0.14.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: just checked "update manager" is upto date

Comment: MAKZ & Xangua i tried these commands and following error

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-
W: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to pk.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/motumedia/libav10-trusty/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/motumedia/libav10-trusty/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @MAKZ there was no need to suggest a Third Party Repository...

Comment: why is your apt-get trying to connect to motumedia ? disable that source.

Answer (score 0):

You can play all kinds of videos in the default media player i.e. Totem also.

Just need to install the plugins for different codecs.

Try this :

```
$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins*
```

I you will have tons formats supported.